# How to transfer data from one page to another using angular js and Java servlets

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs

I have created one login page in angular js and Written a servlet for login action. I am trying to login with username and password. Currently I am able to redirect to Dashboard page after successful login using $window but I want to show that user data also on that page. So how to do that in angularjs and servlets?

Answer (score 0):

Use the HttpServletRequest to get the Remote User.

In your dashboard Controller, fetch the remote User via AJAX (for example). and set the fetched User to $rootScope.

As soon as your DashBoard page loads, the first AJAX call should be to fetch the User and set the fetched User to $rootScope.

Comment: Thanks for you answer but in angularjs I am getting remote user as null after login in dashboard page

Comment: May I know the Security Model you have used for authentication?

Answer (score 0):

on your dashboard just use this
$rootScope.currentUser = <%= HttpServletRequest.getRemoteUser() %>

you can use this directly in html page

Answer (score 0):

You have different choices to store you data using [localStorage](https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage) in angular js eg:

- localStorage
- sesstionStorage

For example following data you have to transfer to another state

```
var user_data = {"user_id": 1,"username": "Alpha"}
```

// To add to local storage

```
localStorageService.set('user_data',user_data);
```

// Read that value back

```
var user_obj = localStorageService.get('user_data');
```

After saving you can get these data from same storage where you saved.

This will really help you.

Please read out [this link](http://gregpike.net/demos/angular-local-storage/demo/demo.html) to get more understnading.

Thanks